# Replace characters in string, but only after a certain point in the string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a huge string I made from a list, I want to replace every ',' with a new line, but only after a certain string that starts with "http". I was using `.replace(",","\n")` but this replaces every one so I need a kind of while loop like this

```
i = str.indexOf(',');
while(i >= 0) {
  System.out.println(i);
  i = str.indexOf(',', i+1);
}
```

then I need to maybe create substrings and check if it has http inside before replacing, I'm no expert and I'm sure there is an easier way.

Comment: Maybe `str = str.replaceAll("(http[^,]*),","$1\n")`?

Comment: First extract the relevant part. Therefore search for your `http` string and split there, for example using `String#substring` and `String#indexOf`. After that use your regular `replaceAll` approach.

Comment: @Zabuza that won't work I'll end up with the same result, imagine a string "hi, hello, how are you, http//myurl.com , goodbye, nice to see you, http//otherurl.com ," I only want it to replace the 2 commas each occur after the http

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'll definitely try this many thanks, I'll comment soon

Comment: How about working on the original list instead of creating the "huge String" first?

Comment: @daniu maybe your right, go through each item in the list removing each comma and then when i call list.string() ill be certain where the commas will be

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? Split by `http` and you'll get intermediate parts. Every part at an odd index is between *http*s and should be replaced. Alternatively use multiple `indexOf` calls, you can tell the method to begin searching from the index of the last seen `http`. By that you'll find all intermediate parts.

Answer (score 4):

```
    String inputStr = "aa.com,bb.com,http://cc.com,b,c,d";
    int httpIndex = inputStr.indexOf("http");
    String result = inputStr.substring(0,httpIndex) + inputStr.substring(httpIndex).replaceAll(",", "\n");
    System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

**result:**

aa.com,bb.com,http://cc.com 
b
c
d

Comment: Works. However it seems OPs input can have multiple `http` occurrences and it should only replace stuff in the parts between the occurrences (see comments). So `split` and then odd indices or multiple `indexOf` calls should do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "http://side.de/servet/patth?jjjj,qwe,rtz,zui,opl";

if ( s.startsWith("http")) {

    s = s.replaceAll(",", "\n");
    System.out.println(s);;
}
```

And output

```
http://side.de/servet/patth?jjjj
qwe
rtz
zui
opl
```

Comment: You should use `s.startsWith` instead.

Comment: yes, it's better with startWith. I improve my answer

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Be careful with how the data is being read. If it's read line by line then the http check will be properly met. Otherwise it'll be one long string and every ',' will be replaced. If you want to read text in the same format as your example. Search for the "http" string and then create a substring from that index. Then run the if statement below.

```
if (s.contains("http")) {
    s = s.replace(",", "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So to implement my previous comment about working on the original list instead of creating the huge String first.

```
static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(.*http)(.*)");

public static <T> String toHugeStringReplacingCommas(List<T> list, Function<T, String> convertToString) {
    // we're collecting a lot of Strings, a StringBuilder is most efficient
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (T item : list) {
        String string = convertToString(item);
        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(string);
        if (m.isMatch(string)) {
            // everything up to and including "http"
            StringBuilder replaced = new StringBuilder(m.groups(1));
            replaced.append(m.groups(2).replaceAll(",", "\n"));
            string = replaced.toString();
        }
        builder.append(string);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

This will do the replacement while you're constructing the "huge String" so it should be much more efficient. It does however require "http" to be present in each item for the rest to be replaced; if it occurs only once overall, you need to keep track of whether it occurred at an earlier time, like this:

```
public static <T> String toHugeStringReplacingCommas(List<T> list, Function<T, String> convertToString) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    boolean httpFound = false;
    for (T item : list) {
        String string = convertToString(item);
        if (!httpFound) {
            Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(string);
            httpFound = m.isMatch(string);
            if (httpFound) {
                // we found the first occurance of "http"
                // append the part up to http without replacing,
                // leave the replacing of the rest to be done outside the loop
                builder.append(m.groups(1));
                string = m.groups(2);
            }
        }
        if (httpFound) {
            string = string.replaceAll(",", "\n");
        }
        builder.append(string);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

If the `List` you're constructing from contains Strings to begin with, you can leave the `T` and `convertToString` stuff out and just do

```
public static String toHugeStringReplacingCommas(List<String> list) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String string : list) {
        // and so on
```